# Smtp Received from IP addresses not matching

Tags: c#, smtp

I am sending emails via SMTP, in C#, to Google Mail and although it is working, there is an issue:

> Received: from 11.111.11.103 (mx101.company.com. [11.111.11.101])
>           by mx.google.com with ESMTP id fw15si12217298wbb.73.2011.12.06.06.44.24;
>           Tue, 06 Dec 2011 06:44:25 -0800 (PST)

I have multiple IP addresses that I send from, and I have configured my `HelloDomain` to be the first IP address (`x.x.x.103`) which can be seen working above (also it's name is `mx103.company.com`).  I was expecting to see the output below:

> Received: from 11.111.11.103 (mx103.company.com. [11.111.11.103])
>           by mx.google.com with ESMTP id fw15si12217298wbb.73.2011.12.06.06.44.24;
>           Tue, 06 Dec 2011 06:44:25 -0800 (PST)

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: you you have posted looks like giberish .. perhaps you could paste exactly what code you are using. have you tried to even ping the name / address..

Comment: There is nothing "gibberish" about what I have posted.  That is what the SMTP server is returning.  I've just amended IP addresses and machine names.

Comment: @"DJ KRAZE" - Looks fine to me - maybe you don't understand what you are looking at?

Comment: @DJKRAZE that's a very standard SMTP header in an email. When you don't understand something it's only gibberish to YOU. Go read a book.

Comment: @DJKRAZE - If you are actually Arsenio Hall - I'll delete my comment - Love your films... (View his site to see a pic)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the answer is configuring your `LocalEndPoint`.  I have been banging my head against the keyboard all day and finally realised that I wasn't assigning the `LocalEndPoint`, which in turn defaulted to the first IP address.